# DELETE FROM causes 100% cpu load and makes database unusable

Tags: mysql

I have a sql command I run every minute to delete old logs on a server. The datatabse contains around 1.5 milion entries.

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE `time` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

This command ususally takes 1-3 seconds to exceute. However, sometimes the command takes minutes and the CPU load goes to 100%.

When I check the process I can see the query

```
 Query   |   422 | updating                     | DELETE FROM....
```

All other queries are "waiting for table lock"

```
Query   |   420 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT...
```

Is there a way I can check why the command sometimes is so slow or a better way to define my query?

Comment: Why do you run this command every minute when the specified interval is `1 WEEK`? Wouldn't there be less overhead, if you actually ran this query once a week?

Comment: it depends on load of the server, indexes that mus be updates, Foreign keys thqat have to be checked and of course of the number of rows and yes all other process that will query the table must wait, becuase it is changeing

Comment: @DarkBee we tried to run it once a day/weeky. but the amount of data which had to be deleted froze the query all the time so we decided to delete every minute to make it less rows which have to be deleted.

Comment: @penguin_P Do you have any index on `time` field?

Comment: @nbk - there is no load on the server before excuting the query. and the database itself has around 1.5 mio entries.

Comment: @Justinas yes, there is an index on time

Comment: Please post the output of `show create table logs` . Are any reference key on `logs` table? Post explain plan , run `explain DELETE FROM logs WHERE time`< NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK` ;

Comment: @penguin_P  how can there be no load and queries waiting for processing

Comment: Maybe issue is that your table gets locked and deletion is waiting in queue. Than issue is not this query.

Comment: Foreign keys in that log table i wonder ?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE logs; so we can see what your are dealing with.

Answer (score -2):

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE `time` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK limit 1000;
```